# How to check consumer group already exists in Redis?

Tags: redis, jedis

Currently I am looking for ellegant solution to check that consumer groups in Redis stream already exist.

I have a few modules which connect to the same stream and read data from it. But they can start in different order and in case consumer groups is not created - try to create it.
In case first module have created group, others get an error according to documentation.

From the documentation:

> If the specified consumer group already exists, the command returns a -BUSYGROUP error.

I would like to avoid this error.

I use Jedis client for work with Redis.
I know there is `XINFO` command (which can returns groups list), but it doesn't work when Redis was started in cluster mode (which can be one of my configuration).

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way, as you covered in your questions there are two options:

1. `XGROUP CREATE` and catch an error in case the group is already there.
2. `XINFO STREAM` and look for the group, but that won't be atomic and a parallel group create, might be called right after you get the info back.

Comment: I opened an issue to improve this: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/9893. The corresponding action in Kafka is idempotent and safe: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html